# SVG Clip-Path not working on a div

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

I am trying to clip path a div with an `id="overlay-circle"` but it doesn't seem to work. Here's my **html code:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <svg>
            <clipPath id="clipPolygon" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                <polygon id="clipPoints" points="0.5, 2 3, 3 0.5" />
            </clipPath>
        </svg>
        <div id="letterWrapper">
            <div id="halo"></div>
            <div id="overlay-circle"></div>
            <div id="letter">
                <div id="letter-spotlight"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's my **CSS:**

```
#overlay-circle
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 39%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 95px;
    width: 95px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, #3f566d 0%, #8f97a7 30%, #fff 100%);
    z-index: 2;
    clip-path: url(#clipPolygon);
}
```

I went through many articles but cannot figure out what is it that I am doing wrong. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: If your CSS is a separate file then there's no clipPolygon in your CSS file. #x is short for <this file>#x Is that your problem?

Comment: Okay I moved that code within <style></style> in the html file but it's all the same. The problem is I have no issues in Opera but firefox does not want to display my svg.

Comment: Your polygon is invalid, the number of points is invalid (an odd number) it must be even as it consists of pairs of coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the `-moz-` prefix you're using for linear gradient. If you've been testing in, say, Chrome, you'll see a blank screen. You need to expand your gradient property support:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, #3f566d 0%, #8f97a7 30%, #fff 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #3f566d 0%, #8f97a7 30%, #fff 100%);
background: linear-gradient(top left, #3f566d 0%, #8f97a7 30%, #fff 100%);
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I don't see how this is related to the clip-path to begin with. I am also testing in one browser only right now so I don't need to support all browsers.